# Making a TextBox Transparent

Tags: c#, textbox, transparency, picturebox, windows-mobile-5.0

I have a TextBox in my Form that I want to let it be tranparent and show a picture that is in a PictureBox, behind it, but how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too complex, after some searching on StackOverflow, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16050862/837726).

Basically, you need to subclass `TextBox` and in its constructor add the appropriate style.

Final stpe, set its `BackColor` to Transparent. Hope it helps.