# TextBox with a Transparent Background 

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I want to do textBox a Transparent Background c# .net 
Visual Studio is making a mistake if you define Properties

Comment: Could you elaborate and show your code?

Comment: I just want to integrate graphics and put the image transparent textbox that hides the graphics

Comment: Sorry this comment is not helping. What did you try? What mistake and Properties are you referring to?

Comment: This is not possible.  You'll have to move to WPF to get it.

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19733917. Tell me if this helps...

Answer (score 4):

Put this in the constructor:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

The class need to enable the transparent style. (For some reason it isn't supported by default).

```
public class MyControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
        public MyControl ()
        {
            // Create visual controls
            InitializeComponent();
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        }
}
```

Or if it's not a custom control:

```
mycontrolObject.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

More about [Control.SetStyle Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx)

Other [Control Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx)

Comment: This will not work for a TextBox. .NET TextBox is just a wrapper for the old Win32 control so he will need to do some kind of sub-classing.

Comment: Even when I sub-classed TextBox this didn't work. I can successfully set the BackColor property to Color.Transparent (it no longer throws an exception), but the textbox is not actually transparent - I cannot see the control behind it.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an easy task. .Net TextBox control is a wrapper around Win32 Edit control, so you will need to do sub-classing to achieve background transparency.

Take a look at this sample: [AlphaBlendTextBox - A transparent/translucent textbox for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/alphablendtextbox.aspx)

Comment: That code project is like a virus.  It isn't a text box, it just looks like one.

Comment: @HansPassant can you confirm that it is a virus? or are you just not impressed with the implementation?

Comment: @Jeremy - it is code that duplicates itself because it looks attractive but gets its users in trouble all the time.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a workaround for this problem, which I have on my own.
Most of what I've read over here is true. And the approaches "à la" `AlphaBlendTextBox` are way too complex or too time-consuming for some environments, already heavily charged.

Assume you have a given background color and a given picture or whatever you want to see through the `RichTextBox` control. This is what I've done (summarized):

1. on the main form, you place the picture, text, buttons or whatever as projected, with the proper background color and / or picture
2. create a new form and position it wherever appropriate
3. set this new form `TransparencyKey` to `SystemColors.InactiveBorder`
4. take care of this form border properties (`FormBorderStyle` to `FormBorderStyle.None`; `ControlBox`,`MinimizeBox`, `MaximizeBox` and `ShowIcon` to `false`, `TopMost` to `true`, `StartPosition` to `FormStartPosition.Manual`, `SizeGripStyle` to `SizeGripStyle.Hide`), so there's no visible form structures
5. create a `RichTextBox` with the same size of the form and located on its upper, left corner
6. set this box `BackColor` to `SystemColors.InactiveBorder` (remember the TransparencyKey?)
   and its `BorderStyle` to None as well
7. take care of textbox contents: color(s), font(s) and strings
8. synchronize this form visibility with whatever you need to and... voilà! You can see your application background through whatever you write and edit on the text box!

I can't pretend this approach fits everybody, but it is way simpler than others I've seen and, as long as I can keep it that way, I do prefer the simpler solutions.

Of course, when you close the main form, you must take care of the child form, but this is pretty basic for you, isn't it?

Enjoy!

Comment: I had pondered something like this but steps 3+6 never crossed my mind. So it works for you?