# Textbox with Semi-Transparent Background

Tags: wpf, xaml

Semi-Transparent background of the Textbox is needed, and the text content should be shown as normal.

**Style** or **Brush** which can store in the Resource dictionary is good.

NOTE:

1. My textBox is wrapped within a ContentControl.
2. This similar question does not help. [TextBox with a Transparent Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557365/textbox-with-a-transparent-background) .

Comment: you can set `Background` property to `Transparent`: `<TextBox Background="Transparent" />`

Comment: @kmatyaszek Could u tell me how to do that in C# code?

Comment: I gave you answer. Check it :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In XAML you can set `Background` property to `Transparent`:

```
<TextBox Background="Transparent" />
```

In code-behind you can use following code:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox 
{
    Width = 100,
    Background = Brushes.Transparent
};
```

If you want to set background to transparent to all `TextBox` you can use following style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It works for a single Textbox, but for some reasons not work for my Textbox wrapped within a ContentControl. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @dongx if you show me more code i will try find out why it's not working. I tried `TextBox` wrapped within a `ContentControl` and it's working in my code.

Comment: Do you know how to set the background to be semi-transparent?

Comment: Finally, it works. The reason is the textbox's style has been overwrote.

Comment: @dongx in the xaml use Opacity like: `<TextBox Background="Red" Opacity="0.5" ... />`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a semi-transparent background in code-behind you can do this

use a dependency prop on a class that inherits from TextBox

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BgColourProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("BgColour", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(myTextBox), null);

public SolidColorBrush BgColour
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(BgColourProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BgColourProperty, value); }
    }
```

then set whatever colour you wish using Color.FromArgb() where 1st argument is Alpha component

```
myTextBox.BgColour = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(120,240, 17, 17));
```