# how to make Textboxes transparent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, textbox

I have 2 texboxes.  textbox1 has default value 0 and textbox2 has nothing.
I want to combine them. Textbox2 has multiline, textbox1 has not.I did the backround colors same(white). So when I combine them it will look as one textbox.
The problem is I want to see the default value of textbox1. For that I need a transparancy for textbox2. 
How can I make textbox2 transparency? 
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16050862/1870760 , but this sounds like an XY problem kind of question : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: windows forms or WPF?

Comment: win forms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050249/transparency-for-windows-forms-textbox

wpf:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984933/textbox-with-semi-transparent-background