# Transparent text box

Tags: winapi, textbox, transparency

I would like to use a transparent read-only text box as a replacement for a label; to allow users to select+copy the text. Exactly what Windows Explorer uses on the file properties window:

[image]

I've found similar question: [Making a TextBox Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716427/850848)

Comments there suggest that proposed solutions do not work with ClearType. But my testing of suggested "AlphaBlendTextBox - A transparent/translucent textbox for .NET" component shows otherwise.

Anyway, the code looks quite complex for such a "simple task". They do save parent control image to a bitmap, drawing that bitmap over and over again with the text on top of it. I would expect there there has to be a solution delegating drawing of the background to parent control.

Possibly their solution is that complex because it allows alpha-blending too. I do not need that. I just want to see a parent background behind the text. Is there a simpler/smarter way?

Note that I'm happy with any winapi solution (pure winapi, MFC, WinForms, Delphi, whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Spy++, it's a typical Edit control with `WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING | WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR | WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` as extended style and `WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY` as original window style.

I've tested it in Win32 and I can confirm that it does what you want it to do.

Also, next time you want to mimic the appearances of other controls, simply fire up Spy++ to get the detailed information about them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will test it. Actually I inspected the control with Spy++ before I asked. But I did not find anything interesting about the styles, so I assumed there must be some wndproc assigned that makes it transparent instead. Do you know which of those styles does the magic?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl exclusion of `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` and inclusion of `ES_READONLY` should do the trick. Again, you can just compare it with a typical editable Edit control and see what the difference is :)