# Usercontrol backcolor according to using form

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

[image]I have created a usercontrol textbox inherited from textbox in which I had set its backcolor property. Now i want that the backcolor should be changed according to that forms's backcolor , which are using it. I have used this.parent.backcolor but it is giving me error. Please suggest a solution.

```
public partial class goodtextbox : TextBox
{
  public goodtextbox()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     //background colour inside textbox
     this.BackColor = Color.LavenderBlush;
     this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
     //font color of textbox
     this.ForeColor = Color.White;
     this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
 }
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
 {
     base.OnPaint(pe);
 }
 protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnEnter(e);
     this.BackColor = Color.Black;
     this.ForeColor = Color.White;
 }
 protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnLeave(e);
     this.BackColor = Color.LavenderBlush;
     this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
 }
```

Comment: "but it is giving me error." we really need to know what this error is, otherwise all our suggestions will be based on guesses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transparency for windows forms textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050249/transparency-for-windows-forms-textbox)

Comment: You're getting that error because you are performing the logic in the control's constructor.  Though the control has been created, it has **not** yet been parented to the owner.

Comment: @MickyD , so what's the solution sir .

Comment: do this in the This.Loaded event rather than the constuctor or make the background transparent.

Comment: Override `OnParentChanged()` or `OnParentBackColorChanged()`

Comment: Note that `this.Parent` not necessarily refers to a Form, it could be any other Container (or even not a Container). Use `FindForm()` to get the top-level Window. In that case, if you just need the Form as reference, you can override `OnHandleCreated()` or `OnLayout()`

Answer (score 1):

Just set the color in the `Loaded` event instead of the constructor. And set it to the control via it's name.

Plus, get the argb code of your desired color, and use`System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(a,r,g,b)` instead of using existing colors.

Good Luck

Comment: It's a Custom Control, there's no Loaded event, plus the Parent can change at any time. The other suggestion doesn't make sense